# 403 Forbidden Error when scraping a site, user-agents already used and updated. Any ideas?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

As the title above states I am getting a 403 error. The URLs generated are valid, I can print them and then open them in my browser just fine.

I've got a user agent, it's the exact same one that my browser sends when accessing the page I want to scrape pulled straight from chrome devtools. I've tried using sessions instead of a straight request, I've tried using urllib, and I've tried using a generic request.get.

Here's the code I'm using, that 403s. Same result with request.get etc.

```py
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
req = session.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

So yeah, I assume I'm not creating the useragent write so it can tell I am scraping. But I'm not sure what I'm missing, or how to find that out.

Comment: server may check other headers too. If it is some API then it may need special headers. Better copy all headers from DevTools and then start removing headers one by one till you see which header makes problem.

Comment: if you need better help then you have to add URL so we could see this page.

Comment: Here's an example URL https://www.g2a.com/lucene/search/filter?&search=The+Elder+Scrolls+V:+Skyrim&currency=nzd&cc=NZD

Comment: I've tried a variety of headers for user agent, not really sure what other header types there are/what I can change.

Comment: in DevTools you can see all headers used by request. Copy all of them.

Comment: I'm actually encountering a similar issue right now, only now it needs "user-agent" and then it works locally.
But doesn't work on a remote Linux machine, or when using wget/curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got all headers from DevTools and I started removing headers one by one and I found it needs only `Accept-Language` and it doesn't need `User-Agent` and it doesn't need Session.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.g2a.com/lucene/search/filter?&search=The+Elder+Scrolls+V:+Skyrim&currency=nzd&cc=NZD'

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = r.json()

print(data['docs'][0]['name'])
```

Result:

```
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition Steam Key GLOBAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some headers as below (not only `User-Agent`):

```
def start_requests(self):
    headers = {        
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',        
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',        
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',        
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',        
        'Cookie': 'AMCV_0D15148954E6C5100A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg=1176715910%7CMCIDTS%7C19271%7CMCMID%7C80534695734291136713728777212980602826%7CMCAAMLH-1665548058%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1665548058%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1664950458s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-19272%7CvVersion%7C5.4.0; s_ecid=MCMID%7C80534695734291136713728777212980602826; __cfruid=37ff2049fc4dcffaab8d008026b166001c67dd49-1664418998; AMCVS_0D15148954E6C5100A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; __cf_bm=NIDFoL5PTkinis50ohQiCs4q7U4SZJ8oTaTW4kHT0SE-1664943258-0-AVwtneMLLP997IAVfltTqK949EmY349o8RJT7pYSp/oF9lChUSNLohrDRIHsiEB5TwTZ9QL7e9nAH+2vmXzhTtE=; PHPSESSID=ddf49facfda7bcb4656eea122199ea0d',                        
        'If-Modified-Since': 'Tue, 04 May 2021 05:09:49 GMT',        
        'If-None-Match': 'W/"12c6a-5c17a16600f6c-gzip"',        
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',        
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',        
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',        
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',        
        'TE': 'trailers',        
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',        
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'        
    }
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, headers=headers)
```